# Freemarker error message 'For "%" left-hand operand'

Tags: freemarker, clickdimension

Having issues getting an email sent out that had previously worked for a year sending through ClickDimensions, but now only showing an error message in sent email events when using this URL (it sends fine without this url, only has issues with it when in the html):

```
 ${Recipient.contact.cd_marketingsummaryinformation.cd_marketingsummaryinformation.cd_autologinurl[0]!''}&amp;returnURL=www.website.com
```

Full error message (Render Error):

For "%" left-hand operand: Expected a number, but this has evaluated to a node+sequence+hash+string (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl wrapped into f.e.dom.ElementModel):
==> Recipient.contact.cd_marketingsummaryinformation.cd_marketingsummaryinformation.cd_autologinurl[0]! [in template "HTML" at line 130, column 378]

Does anyone have experience in reading what the above error message is pointing the issue to? Would it be a CRM schema side or email platform / freemarker mis-interpretation? or something completely different?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you inside an `#escape` directive that uses `%` maybe?

Comment: You're right, in the URL <a href> link, it converts the #escape closing brackets '{' into ASCII Hex '%7B' but in other non <a href> enclosed copy, it doesn't. Are there any ways in which the URL can keep the { as is? It's never been an issue before when sending through ClickDimensions but all of a sudden it is.

Comment: Printing `%`-s, however they were produced, shouldn't cause any problems, because the output is not parsed by FreeMarker. Can you show that `#escape` directive?